# Como salvar elementos no localStorage e enviar para outra pagina?

Tags: localstorage

Gostaria de salvar alguns campos da minha pagina principal e enviar para minha pagina "carrinho".
Ex: gostaria de salvar o titulo de um produto para exibir em outra pagina sem usar banco de dados.

O que eu tenho até o momento:

HTML: `<h1 class="tituloProd">Arroz Tio João integral tipo 1 - 5KG</h1>`

JS:

```
  $('#btnCompra').click (function(){
      localStorage.setItem('tituloProd', $(".tituloProd").val());
      console.log(tituloProd);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se for no mesmo Domínio vc consegue acessar em qualquer página.

EX:
url: www.meusite.com.br/compra/

> > localStorage.setItem("carrinho","Blabla")

url: www.meusite.com.br/carrinho/

> > localStorage.getItem("carrinho")
> >
> > "Blabla"

EDITANDO:
Pra ficar mais facil:

Acessando o arquivo direto na pasta EX: c://projeto/paginas/index.html e c://projeto/paginas/page2.html é como se vc tivesse simplesmente 2 sites diferentes e por isso seu localStorage não consegue se comunicar com as duas pastas.

É necessá que vc crie um servidor que mostre essas duas paginas e ai sim vc vai conseguir usar o localStorage da maneira desejada. Criar um servidor não é dificil.

Primeiro vc instala o node, caso não tenha.
https://nodejs.org/en/

Faça essa estrutura de pastas

```
projeto:
--paginas:
----index.html
----page2.html
--js:
----index.js
--css:
----style.css
--img:
--server.js
```

abra terminal ou cmd na pasta projetos.

Digite

> npm init -y

Isso vai criar um arquivo package.json para gerenciar seu projeto.

Em seguida digite:

> npm i --save-dev express

Isso vai baixar o Express que vai ajudar a montar seu mini servidor.

Depois abra o arquivo server.js e digite:

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express();

const path = require('path')
server.get('/', function(req, res) {
       res.sendFile(__dirname + "/paginas/index.html");
       // Cria a rota para a home do seu site que vai ser quando vc não digitar nada
});

server.get('/page2', function(req, res) {
       res.sendFile(__dirname + "/paginas/page2.html");
       // Cria a rota para a page2 do seu site que vai ser quando vc digitar /page2
});
server.listen(8084);
console.log('Servidor rodando na porta 8084');
```

PRONTO já está tudo configurado.

sua pasta vai ficar parecido com isso:

```
projeto:
--node_modules:

--paginas:
----index.html
----page2.html
--js:
----index.js
--css:
----style.css
--img:
--server.js
--package.json
```

No seu terminal digite:

> node ./server.js

isso vai iniciar seu servidor na porta 8084 do seu localhost.

agora basta acessar;

http://localhost:8084/
q vc vai para sua home.

e se digitar:
http://localhost:8084/page2 
vai para page2

dessa forma as duas paginas pertencem agora ao mesmo dominio "localhost" e vc pode usar o localStorage

Comment: no lugar do "blablabla" eu gostaria de salvar um campo, entao faço localStorage.setItem("carrinho","$(".titulo").val()") ?

Comment: pois eu fiz o teste, e o navegador me retornou "undefined" (console.log(localStorage.getItem("tituloProd"));)

Comment: Como está a estrutura de seu projeto? Por exemplo. Se vc está com uma pasta no seu diretório local e lá tem dois arquivos html, eles podem ser considerados dois "sites" diferentes. Já se vc cria um projeto Django ou em Node etc, vc cria um domínio local (localhost:8080/) que possui varias paginas.

Comment: eu tenho uma pasta "paginas" "js" "css" "img" e os htmls estao na pasta "paginas"